# Checking the keys inside of the keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

Is there a way to check the inner keys inside of the dictionary keys and if the element has the key element inside, returning the corresponding value from a dictionary.

e.g. check if there s any element that `"Hello"` is in the key tuple's second element, and if it exists, return the corresponding value.

```
d = {(1, "Hello"): "a", (2, "Bye"): "b"}
key = "Hello"
# Since "Hello" exist in d's key's element(second position), return "a"
```

Comment: Not without iterating over all of the keys

Comment: `d[[v for v in d if key in v[1]][0]]` through iteration ofcourse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using next (which will return as soon match is found).
By setting default return to None we ensure we don't get the StopIteration error and we can now go ahead and use dictionaries `get` function.

Note that this will in most cases be quicker than a full lookup.

```
key = 'Hello'
d.get(next((t for t in d if key in t), None))
```

Returns:

```
'a'
```

Comment: Neat trick! Probably the best answer so far, succinct and simple.

Comment: @Idlehands Yeah thanks, next is great for lookup when 1 match is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the key tuples, check if the second value of the tuple equals what you want (e.g. "hello"), and if it does then return the value for that key. Something like this:

```
d = {(1, "Hello"): "a", (2, "Bye"): "b"}
key = "Hello"
for k in d:
    if k[1] == key:
        return d[k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of all key tuples that contain the key; grab the first element of that list, and use it as an index to `d`.

```
>>> d = {(1, "Hello"): "a", (2, "Bye"): "b"}
>>> key = "Hello"
>>> d[[key_tuple for key_tuple in d if key in key_tuple][0]]
'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes; however, you have to iterate over every key in your dictionary until you find the "inner key" you are looking for. The code looks like this:

```
d = {(1, "Hello"): "a", (2, "Bye"): "b"}
key = "Hello"

for k in d.keys():
    if key in k:
        print(d[k])
```

You can check if an element exists in a tuple with Python's `in` keyword. This allows you to check if your `key` is an "inner key" *anywhere* inside your key.

This code will print `a` as the output.